# access a js function/class from another file

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, module

I have the following function/class sitting in a file called "errors.js":

```
HB.errors.handleErrorResponse = function(data, form, status) {
    HB.FormButtons.deactivateButtons(HB.errors.formSubmitButton);
    $('#_ignoreDoubleBooking').toggle((status == HB.errors.HTTP_CODE_CONFLICT));

    if (data) {
        HB.Reservation.Listeners.handle40xResponse(data);
    } else {
        HB.Reservation.Listeners.handle50xResponse();
    }
};
```

however `HB.Reservation.Listeners.handle40xResponse()` is siting in another file within the same directory.

What is the best way of obtaining access to "HB.Reservation.Listeners.handle40xResponse()" from errors.js?

Answer (score 1):

You probably will be interested by requirejs (http://requirejs.org/). This is a JavaScript file and module loader. The website documentation is very understandable.